# Problem building an rtl8723 driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, make

We all know the problems with **RTL8723 wireless card** and some people achieved to install but i can't. I have Ubuntu 12.10. When I do the `make` in terminal, it gives me this error

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-37-generic/build M=/home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-37-generic'
CC [M]  /home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o
In file included from /home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:39:0:
/home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/pci.h:245:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl_pci_probe’
/home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: error: ‘IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In function ‘rtl_action_proc’:
/home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:870:25: error: ‘RX_FLAG_MACTIME_MPDU’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In function ‘rtl_send_smps_action’:
/home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:1432:16: error: ‘struct <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘sta’
make[2]: *** [/home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/adrian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-37-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem the fix was simple just upgrade the kernel
you need the latest kernel version i suggest 3.12

1. Go here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
2. Download 3 (maybe 4) debs to a folder somewhere:

linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_all.deb

linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb

linux-image-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb

linux-image-extra-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb   # if available

3.Install the debs with whatever package manager front-end you use (is gdebi still around?), or use these commands:

cd /path/to/folder/where/you/put/the/debs

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Comment: The two links you gave me aren't working

Comment: you can download the latest from from the site below depending on your version of Ubuntu.  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: I have now installed kernel 3.12.8 and again it doesn't let me make the install

Comment: but the driver should be the in  kernel 3.12.8 send me the print  uname -a and lshw