# Wifi problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and RTL8723ae

Tags: wireless, drivers

My laptop MSi S12 has a RTL8723ae PCI card with Ubuntu 14.04 on board. It doesn't detect wi-fi networks.

I tried the answers from [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2169602&page=2) and [Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized) but `make` fails.

How can I fix this issue?

UPDATE:

1) Fail with "make" drivers is the same like here - [Problem building an rtl8723 driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436380/problem-building-an-rtl8723-driver) . And, in my case rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012.tar.gz gave me the same error (I suppose drivers have trouble with 3.13 kernel).

2) Wireles modules looks OK:

```
alex@gendalf:~$ lsmod | grep ^rtl 
rtl8723ae              76506  0 
rtl8723_common         22417  1 rtl8723ae
rtl_pci                26314  1 rtl8723ae
rtlwifi                52835  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723ae
```

3) A little bit more information

```
alex@gendalf:~$ iwconfig 
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`

Comment: what exactly do you mean by make fails?

Comment: Please, looke update

Comment: Did you somehow manage to fix the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [rtl8723ae unstable on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/629679/rtl8723ae-unstable-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I had the same problem but I fixed it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/706557/msi-st-12-laptop-wirless-drive-rt8723ae-doesnt-find-any-nearby-routers

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced much better performance with this network card following the advice from this user:

https://zach-adams.com/2014/06/fixing-rtl8723ae-driver-ubuntu-linux/

In short, two stages:

1. Try installing the linux-firmware-nonfree drivers with this command:

   `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`
2. Try installing the WICD network manager. For instructions for your version of Ubuntu, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

Comment: This doesn't work. It didn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

I have problem with rtl8723ae when i am using windows 8.After changing os from windows 8.1 it automatically installed wifi driver.After that i changed os windows 8.1 to ubuntu 14.04.
check their official website for more details.

Comment: I do not understand. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Click this link for more details.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized

Comment: Can you update your answer with the link?

Comment: this is the driver download link
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57056576/DRIVERS/REALTEK/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012.tar.gz
click the below link for more details
http://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work

Comment: That older driver file is unlikely to compile on 14.04. In fact, the driver rtl8723ae is already included in 14.04. Is it not working as expected? What are your symptoms? Are there any clues in the message log? dmesg | grep rtl Thanks.