# Wifi problem with RTL8723ae on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, realtek

I have the same notebook and problem as the person here: [Wifi problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and RTL8723ae](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499478/wifi-problem-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-rtl8723ae)

I have tried everything including the suggestions provided there (I installed the non-free drivers and WICD but no use. No wireless networks are shown in the list.

```
lshw -C network WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.  
 *-network               
        description: Wireless interface
        product: RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
        logical name: wlan0
        version: 00
        serial: 54:27:1e:d0:72:1f
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723ae driverversion=3.13.0-43-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no
multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:24 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea03fff


dmesg | grep rtl [   13.865686] rtl8723ae: Using firmware
rtlwifi/rtl8723fw_B.bin [   13.986526] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate
control algorithm 'rtl_rc' [   13.989656] rtlwifi: wireless switch is
on
```

What is the problem? I am clueless

Comment: Why are you trying to build this driver?  A working rtl8723ae driver has been included in the standard Ubuntu distributions for over two years.

Comment: Didn't try to build a driver. I don't have any WLAN networks in the list. Either the driver in the distribution does not work (it also does not work in the live version) or I am clueless.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rtl8723ae unstable on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/629679/rtl8723ae-unstable-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Had the same problem and fixed it (see accepted answer) http://askubuntu.com/questions/706557/msi-st-12-laptop-wirless-drive-rt8723ae-doesnt-find-any-nearby-routers

Answer (score 0):

Go into network manager at top right corner of the screen and click on edit connections > wireless tab and set IPV6 to ignore.

Now open the terminal CTRL+ALT+T then copy and paste the following code one line at a time for accuracy:

```
echo "options rtl8723ae swenc=1 ips=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723ae.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rtl8723ae
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723ae
```

IF the issue persists, try compiling new driver. Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change anything.

Comment: Also, I have searched for a long time and could not find a current driver.

Comment: Finally, I just returned the notebook and got another one, which works fine.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, it's a pain. Has anyone solved it? I even compiled the drivers