# MSI ST 12 Laptop Wirless drive RT8723AE doesn't find any nearby routers

Tags: wireless, drivers

> Follow up on: [Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized)

I have the exact same problem as described in the person's previous question.
To elaborate on my current situation; I right now use a Netgear USB wireless dongle to connect to the wireless.

Here's some information:
Contents of the wireless script from ubuntuforums:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 08 Dec 2015 20:44 CET +0100

Booted last: 08 Dec 2015 20:03 CET +0100

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-45-generic #60~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, intermap=off, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Xubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2114]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:10f5]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13d3:3394 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0155 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
6: phy5: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8723ae             166569  0 
msi_wmi                13354  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 msi_wmi
btcoexist             183378  1 rtl8723ae
rtl_pci                39740  1 rtl8723ae
rtlwifi               101788  3 btcoexist,rtl_pci,rtl8723ae
mac80211              652777  2 rtl_pci,rtlwifi
cfg80211              498458  3 mac80211,rtlwifi,8812au
wmi                    19193  1 msi_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:36 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager
    Wicd

Running:

root       960     1  0 20:03 ?        00:00:02 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723ae
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            alx
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########


##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Amsterdam (based on set time zone)

country NL:
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (N/A, 20), NO-OUTDOOR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 40), (N/A, 20), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS
    (5490 - 5710 @ 40), (N/A, 27), DFS
    (57240 - 65880 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), NO-OUTDOOR

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723ae]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723ae/rtl8723ae.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723efw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     D38CC5BB27934DDBA952C9B
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,btcoexist
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     1BFD9F9E9693CB93908149A
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     9A94C1A2CE5E02B2F239836
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     315DCE1E2614AE1F38132D3
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C1:A3:1E:DB:9F:C4:C6:4E:2D:95:A7:FF:18:A6:73:D1:8C:AB:15:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D48679749A6B8B822E391CA
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C1:A3:1E:DB:9F:C4:C6:4E:2D:95:A7:FF:18:A6:73:D1:8C:AB:15:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723ae]
debug: 1
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: Y
ips: N
swenc: Y
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc
fuse

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf]
options rtl8192ce ips=1
options rtl8192ce fwlps=0
options rtl8192ce swenc=1

##### rc.local ##########################

rfkill block bluetooth

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x1969:0x1091 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8723 (rtl8723ae)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8812au)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"

##### dmesg #############################

[ 2197.313311] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> [BTCoex] Get bt info by fw!!
[ 2197.313320] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_inq_page_monitor():<0-0> [BTCoex], BT Inquiry/page started time : 0x0, cur_time : 0x73ca9
[ 2197.313327] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_2_ant_common_action():<0-0> Wifi idle + Bt idle, bt coex mechanism always off!!
[ 2197.313333] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> Action 2-Ant common.
[ 2197.313339] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_same_coexist_state():<0-0> [DM][BT], Coexist state do not chang!!
[ 2199.317197] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist():<0-0> [DM][BT], bt_dm_coexist start
[ 2199.317327] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> High Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x770)=0(0)/2(2)
[ 2199.317339] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> Low Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x774)=0(0)/0(0)
[ 2199.317347] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_8723():<0-0> [BTCoex], 2 Ant mechanism
[ 2199.317353] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> [BTCoex] Get bt info by fw!!
[ 2199.317361] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_inq_page_monitor():<0-0> [BTCoex], BT Inquiry/page started time : 0x0, cur_time : 0x73e9e
[ 2199.317369] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_2_ant_common_action():<0-0> Wifi idle + Bt idle, bt coex mechanism always off!!
[ 2199.317374] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> Action 2-Ant common.
[ 2199.317381] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_same_coexist_state():<0-0> [DM][BT], Coexist state do not chang!!
[ 2201.321503] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist():<0-0> [DM][BT], bt_dm_coexist start
[ 2201.321631] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> High Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x770)=0(0)/1(1)
[ 2201.321642] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> Low Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x774)=0(0)/0(0)
[ 2201.321650] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_8723():<0-0> [BTCoex], 2 Ant mechanism
[ 2201.321657] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> [BTCoex] Get bt info by fw!!
[ 2201.321665] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_inq_page_monitor():<0-0> [BTCoex], BT Inquiry/page started time : 0x0, cur_time : 0x74093
[ 2201.321672] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_2_ant_common_action():<0-0> Wifi idle + Bt idle, bt coex mechanism always off!!
[ 2201.321678] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> Action 2-Ant common.
[ 2201.321684] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_same_coexist_state():<0-0> [DM][BT], Coexist state do not chang!!
[ 2203.325434] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist():<0-0> [DM][BT], bt_dm_coexist start
[ 2203.325560] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> High Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x770)=0(0)/2(2)
[ 2203.325566] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> Low Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x774)=0(0)/0(0)
[ 2203.325571] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_8723():<0-0> [BTCoex], 2 Ant mechanism
[ 2203.325574] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> [BTCoex] Get bt info by fw!!
[ 2203.325579] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_inq_page_monitor():<0-0> [BTCoex], BT Inquiry/page started time : 0x0, cur_time : 0x74288
[ 2203.325583] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_2_ant_common_action():<0-0> Wifi idle + Bt idle, bt coex mechanism always off!!
[ 2203.325586] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> Action 2-Ant common.
[ 2203.325589] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_same_coexist_state():<0-0> [DM][BT], Coexist state do not chang!!
[ 2205.329433] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist():<0-0> [DM][BT], bt_dm_coexist start
[ 2205.329559] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> High Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x770)=0(0)/1(1)
[ 2205.329566] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> Low Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x774)=0(0)/0(0)
[ 2205.329571] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_8723():<0-0> [BTCoex], 2 Ant mechanism
[ 2205.329575] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> [BTCoex] Get bt info by fw!!
[ 2205.329580] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_inq_page_monitor():<0-0> [BTCoex], BT Inquiry/page started time : 0x0, cur_time : 0x7447d
[ 2205.329584] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_2_ant_common_action():<0-0> Wifi idle + Bt idle, bt coex mechanism always off!!
[ 2205.329588] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> Action 2-Ant common.
[ 2205.329591] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_same_coexist_state():<0-0> [DM][BT], Coexist state do not chang!!
[ 2207.333799] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist():<0-0> [DM][BT], bt_dm_coexist start
[ 2207.334041] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> High Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x770)=0(0)/2(2)
[ 2207.334048] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> Low Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x774)=0(0)/0(0)
[ 2207.334054] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_8723():<0-0> [BTCoex], 2 Ant mechanism
[ 2207.334058] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> [BTCoex] Get bt info by fw!!
[ 2207.334064] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_inq_page_monitor():<0-0> [BTCoex], BT Inquiry/page started time : 0x0, cur_time : 0x74672
[ 2207.334069] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_2_ant_common_action():<0-0> Wifi idle + Bt idle, bt coex mechanism always off!!
[ 2207.334072] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> Action 2-Ant common.
[ 2207.334076] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_same_coexist_state():<0-0> [DM][BT], Coexist state do not chang!!
[ 2209.337877] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist():<0-0> [DM][BT], bt_dm_coexist start
[ 2209.338003] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> High Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x770)=0(0)/1(1)
[ 2209.338009] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> Low Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x774)=0(0)/0(0)
[ 2209.338013] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_8723():<0-0> [BTCoex], 2 Ant mechanism
[ 2209.338017] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> [BTCoex] Get bt info by fw!!
[ 2209.338022] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_inq_page_monitor():<0-0> [BTCoex], BT Inquiry/page started time : 0x0, cur_time : 0x74867
[ 2209.338026] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_2_ant_common_action():<0-0> Wifi idle + Bt idle, bt coex mechanism always off!!
[ 2209.338029] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> Action 2-Ant common.
[ 2209.338032] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_same_coexist_state():<0-0> [DM][BT], Coexist state do not chang!!
[ 2211.342209] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist():<0-0> [DM][BT], bt_dm_coexist start
[ 2211.342337] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> High Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x770)=0(0)/2(2)
[ 2211.342348] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> Low Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x774)=0(0)/0(0)
[ 2211.342356] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_8723():<0-0> [BTCoex], 2 Ant mechanism
[ 2211.342363] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> [BTCoex] Get bt info by fw!!
[ 2211.342371] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_inq_page_monitor():<0-0> [BTCoex], BT Inquiry/page started time : 0x0, cur_time : 0x74a5c
[ 2211.342378] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_2_ant_common_action():<0-0> Wifi idle + Bt idle, bt coex mechanism always off!!
[ 2211.342384] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> Action 2-Ant common.
[ 2211.342390] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_same_coexist_state():<0-0> [DM][BT], Coexist state do not chang!!
[ 2213.346396] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist():<0-0> [DM][BT], bt_dm_coexist start
[ 2213.346517] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> High Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x770)=0(0)/2(2)
[ 2213.346529] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_bt_hw_counters_monitor():<0-0> Low Priority Tx/Rx (reg 0x774)=0(0)/0(0)
[ 2213.346537] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_8723():<0-0> [BTCoex], 2 Ant mechanism
[ 2213.346543] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> [BTCoex] Get bt info by fw!!
[ 2213.346552] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_inq_page_monitor():<0-0> [BTCoex], BT Inquiry/page started time : 0x0, cur_time : 0x74c51
[ 2213.346559] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_2_ant_common_action():<0-0> Wifi idle + Bt idle, bt coex mechanism always off!!
[ 2213.346565] rtl8723ae:_rtl8723e_dm_bt_coexist_2_ant():<0-0> Action 2-Ant common.
[ 2213.346571] rtl8723ae:rtl8723e_dm_bt_is_same_coexist_state():<0-0> [DM][BT], Coexist state do not chang!!
[ 2223.670675] Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723fw_B.bin
[ 2223.672718] ieee80211 phy5: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[ 2223.673582] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 2224.079562] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

What I did to generate this information:

- I unplugged my usb-wifi adapter
- Rebooted the computer
- Ran the script
- Plugged in the usb-wifi adapter
- Pasted output to question.

About the drivers I could find:

- I have tried the dropbox link but it doesn't work probably because of the `-BT` extension (would be my best guess - but `make` failed really bad and when that happens I have no clue what step B is).
- I have succefully installed the driver at https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new. I installed it with the following steps:

  - `make`
  - `sudo make install`
  - `sudo modprobe rtl8723ae`

The wifi does 'turn on' but `iwlist scan wlan0` returns `No scan results`.

I have to say I'm not really a rocket scientist when it comes to wireless drivers but I would love to see it work. Thanks for any help and if you need more information please comment on this question and don't be a dick.

**Updates**

- 2015-12-14 | Removed some of the routers listed in the script above + [fixed the problem!](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/78#event-491333324)
- 2015-12-12 | Did a git pull as suggested in github issue. Also no effect since the only changes made were to the `rtl8723be` and not `rtl8723ae` driver.
- 2015-12-12 | Put laptop really close to the router had no effect
- 2015-12-08 | updated the wireless script without the usb wifi attached.
- 2015-12-08 | Replied to a similair question on github: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/34
- 2015-12-08 | ndiswrapper is not the culprit - updated the wireless script with the usb wifi attached.
- 2015-12-08 | Will try the answer for ndiswrapper tonight.
- 2015-12-08 | Also tried the `rock` and `troy` branches from the lwfinger github repo. No success yet.
- 2015-12-07 | Updated the `wireless_script` result
- 2015-12-06 | Succesfully installed rtlwifi and modprobed it from github link above - still it doesn't find any router..

Comment: What 'didn't work out' about the rtlwifi_new version? What were the errors? Maybe we can help.

Comment: I updated the question to the current situation

Comment: @chili555 In short: `iwlist scan wlan0` doesn't find any network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following:

I [asked the developer](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/78) of the `rtlwifi` driver to check if something was wrong. He told me the `msi` option was missing from the driver.

Steps to now setup a correct driver:

1. Clone project: `git clone git@github.com:lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git`
   (or you can just download .zip and extract somewhere)
2. Build project: `make; sudo make install`
3. Remove the old mod: `sudo rmmod rtl8723ae`
4. Set the mod with the msi flag: `sudo modprobe rtl8723ae msi=1`

Tada. Wifi!

p. s. You can set option msi=1 for automatic loading by creating a file in
/etc/modprobe.d

Answer (score 0):

I believe ndiswrapper is interfering. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper-common
sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper.conf
```

Reboot and let us see:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

You have the correct driver in place, so I assume the *rtlwifi_new* went just fine.

Comment: I'll try to see if that will work :) thanks for the response.

Comment: I'm sorrry but this doesn't work. I already removed both of the packages some long time ago. And the `.conf` file doesn't exist or was also already removed once.  Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: "What I did to generate this information: - I unplugged my usb-wifi adapter - Rebooted the computer - Ran the script - Plugged in the usb-wifi adapter - Pasted output to question." The wireless script clearly shows the USB inserted and connected.

Comment: Yes, I updated the script just now. Otherwise I have to take the usb-adapter out, run the script, put it back in and paste the information. I'm rather lazy when it comes to that. But I'll paste the info without the usb-adapter.

Comment: Does it see your network if you are very close to the router; one meter or so? Reference: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304607&page=2 post #19.

Comment: My router is about ~3-4 meters away in the same room. I'll check tonight if it matters though if I'm sitting next to it. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I parked my laptop right next to the router and it still doesn't work. I did pull the latest changes for the driver from the `rtlwifi` git repo. Also, still no succes.