# Wireless Adapter RTL8821CE Not Working in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, wireless, adapter, 19.04

The following is part of the output shown from the `lshw -C network` command. The wireless adapter is seen by the OS but it seems that the drivers are not working. I tried installing the driver but to no avail.

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
version: 00
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

Please, any idea on how to solve this issue in Ubuntu 19.04.I had this same issue while using 18.04 and managed to solve it. But when i just upgraded to 19.04, the issue started but the previous solution seems not to be working this time.

Comment: Try the answer of pHeLiOn  on [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For updates:

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce.git
cd rtl8821ce
sudo apt install gcc
sudo apt install make
sudo make all
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -a 8821ce
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8821ce msi=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8821ce.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

For kernel version >= 5.0 the `ok_access` function supports only two parameters, while for earlier kernel versions 4.* or less it has three parameters. Try the below code with updated parameters

```
git clone https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce.git
cd rtl8821ce
sudo make all
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -a 8821ce
```

Comment: This worked for a while on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and 19.10 but later the wireless connection had vert poor signal receptions even though the wireless router is close by.

Answer (score 0):

try the answer on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763797/how-to-install-rtl8723ae-driver-on-ubuntu-16-04/763944#763944), mine worked for rtl8723ae after i ran the 3 commands. I've substituted yours ...

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8821ce msi=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8821ce.conf
exit
```

Comment: Keno has RTL8821CE card but it seems that commands you provided are for RTL8723AE.

Comment: Thanks guys for the solutions offered. Now after a fresh installation of another Ubuntu 18.04, the results were awesome. I did not have to even do a reboot before the wireless adapter came up.  The result of the command lshw -C network is now: *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00